# Использование двух типов для одной переменной в typescript

Tags: typescript

Переношу js на typescript, столкнулся с проблемой. Нижеописанная функция работает с двумя типами данных, вижу вот такую ошибку:

```
Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'Operation | OperationCreated'. 
Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'OperationCreated'
```

```js
type DateTime = {
  date: string;
};

type Operation = {
  dateTime: DateTime;
};

type OperationCreated = {
  createdDate: string;
};

const sortByDate = (o1: Operation | OperationCreated, o2: Operation | OperationCreated) =>
  stringToMillisecond(o1.createdDate || o1.dateTime.date) - stringToMillisecond(o2.createdDate || o2.dateTime.date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS запутался :) Если дело идёт о составных типах то прийдётся однозначно сообщать тайпскрипту в каком случае какой параметр использовать. Как-то так:

```
type DateTime = {
  date: string;
};

type Operation = {
  dateTime: DateTime;
};

type OperationCreated = {
  createdDate: string;
};

const sortByDate = (o1: Operation | OperationCreated, o2: Operation | OperationCreated) =>
  stringToMillisecond((o1 as OperationCreated).createdDate || (o1 as Operation).dateTime.date) - stringToMillisecond((o2 as OperationCreated).createdDate || (o2 as Operation).dateTime.date);
```

На самом деле это способ заткнуть систему тревоги. TS во всю сигналит о возможной проблеме, которая обязательно возникнет если у объекта типа `OperationCreated` поле `dateTime` вдруг окажется пустой строкой.

Если честно, можно обойтись от подобных решений объединения типов, тогда код будет чуть более надёжный. Но прийдётся немного привыкнуть к TS и отвыкнуть от JS.

Answer (score 3):

Вместо

```
o1: Operation | OperationCreated
```

можно написать

```
o1: Partial<Operation & OperationCreated>
```

Тогда написанный код будет лучше компилироваться, но восклицательные знаки добавить придётся:

```
stringToMillisecond(o1.createdDate || o1.dateTime!.date)
```